# How to calculate hash code for a mix of numbers and strings uniquely using C# and T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to calculate a unique code for several int, double and string values.

The actual challenge is that code generated for a particular set of values must be same in C# and in T-SQL.

I use C# 3.5 and SQL 2008

Comment: A hash code or a unique code, which one?

Comment: What format does the hash code need to be in? If there's no limit to the length of the code, you could just concatenate them into one big string.

Comment: unique code.... although there is no limit I would prefer to have an 4-8 byte int... I already do concatentation but it looks really ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post more detail why you need something like this.
BTW is you drop the "4-8 bytes" requirement, you can simply compute MD5/SHA1 hash of the values. In C# use `MD5CryptographicProvider`, in SQL server `hashbytes( 'MD5', @values)`

Comment: I was looking for something like that. Let me test this thoroughly. Thank you